# Automatic redirection not explicable

Tags: php, symfony

In my LoginForm (username, password) I inserted a html link for forgotten passwords (/psw_forgotten). here are my routes :

```
psw_forgotten:
path: /psw_forgotten
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Login:psw_forgotten }

psw_forgotten_check:
path: /psw_forgotten_check
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Login:psw_forgotten_check }

psw_login:
path: /login
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Login:login }

psw_login_check:
path: /login_check
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Login:login_check }
```

When I click the link, the psw_fogotten route is called but there is an automatic redirection to the psw_login route.

In firebug I can see:

```
GET psw_forgotten 302 Found
GET Login 200 OK
....
```

There is no code in the Login controller for psw_forgotten route but I have no error, proving that it does not even try to go there.

Can you help ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe it's overkill, but why don't you use FOSUserBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route for psw_forgetten_check is into a firewall symfony.
You must declare this route out of firewall security symfony.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell SF that this route do not need authentication protection in app/config/security.yml file:

```
access_control:
        #Forgot Password
        - { path: ^your-path-to-forgot-pwd, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```